# 10/100Mbps Magnetics with 10/100/1000 PHY

Tags: ethernet, magnetics, phy, gigabit

I have a SOC that has a KSZ9031RN PHY, that is a Gigabit PHY. But I'm going to use only in 10/100 Mode with 4 wires.

Gigabit PHY datasheet recommends a magnetic for Gigabit Ethernet, that are different from Fast Ethernet magnetics.

Can I use 4 Wire Fast Ethernet magnetic with that Gigabit PHY if I'm going to use it only in 10/100 Mode?

Thanks!

Comment: The devil's in the detail and I see none.

Comment: What do you refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes you can use the KSZ9031RN with only 10/100 magnetics.

Read the [Support datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002117F.pdf) and note section 3.8.

[image]

So you will have to program the devices to ensure it does not attempt to size 4-pair as opposed to 2-pair connections.